Why do we use only event history for temporal point processes?
I'm trying to understand temporal points processes. In particular, neural TPPs. In all the works I've read, the only features fed into the model are a sequence of event timestamps and marks if they exist. They encode this using some RNN and then use the hidden state to parametrize a hazard function.
Why only use these features? To me, it seems like a very simplistic input to be able to predict the behaviour of complex systems. Wouldn't providing extra features (say e.g. if you try to predict sales of ice-creams, the temperature) be useful?
On a similar note, why provide only information about exactly when events happened? Would it be helpful to also encode some recent information of the system (e.g. ice-cream example, not only temperature when ice-creams were sold but also over the last 24 hours to know if a sale is likely now).
Perhaps this stems from a misunderstanding I have about TPPs. Any pointers toward relevant literature would be really helpful!
